# Windows WPF Resolution

Tags: wpf

How do I get my WPF window to fit any screen resolution, because I have a resolution of 1920 x 1080 and when I switch to a lower resolution I lose the Controls in a view because the window does not fit, did not include example code because I have no idea how.

Comment: WPF use device independent unit you should not have this problem. Maybe root of your problem is in layout. Could you post your XAML code?

Comment: Read http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41 to understand WPF Resolution Independent.

Comment: You can start by redoing your UI properly, by coding your XAML manually and using proper layout containers instead of using the Visual Studio designer which generates things like `Margin="545,1512.52,-2243.2,-323498"` and the like.

Comment: Makes me cringe when I see people dragging stuff around the designer... they should disable editing in it in VS and make you have to use Blend full stop for that stuff

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into panel overview  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152(v=vs.110).aspx

Also I`ll suggest you for "Auto" and "*" sizing http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Hope this help you......